# How to reseed/replace identity columns on existing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hey all I want to reseed my IDENTITY COLUMN values starting from 1 I know how to do this with DBCC CHECKIDENT, however, I would like to replace the value in all existing rows.. This table has a little over 2 million rows.

What is the best approach for this task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply add a new identity column, a la [How to add a new identity column to a table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698793/how-to-add-a-new-identity-column-to-a-table-in-sql-server). Just delete the old column and re-add it.  This will break any foreign keys, of course, but I assume since you are re-numbering everything I am guessing that's ok.

Comment: If you have forign key relationships, I'd suggest preserving the old column until you can update all the child tables with the new id value. They you can drop it.

Comment: The problem with that is that SQL Server cannot have multiple identity columns in a table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349092/can-a-sql-server-table-have-two-identity-columns.  You'd need to remove the identity attribute from the old one first.

Comment: YEs, that is true you need to remove the identity property.

Answer (score 2):

See this example how to replace values, but RESEED is something else:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id INT IDENTITY)
GO
INSERT t DEFAULT VALUES
GO 25

SET IDENTITY_INSERT t ON

delete t 

OUTPUT DELETED.Id+100 INTO T(Id)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT t Off

SELECT * FROM t

DROP TABLE t
```

An example of **reseed**:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('YourTableName', 150, reseed)
```

**AND**

If you have to replace the value - with 2M rows it definitely have to take time